# Undefined index: id, when I save the options

Tags: wp-debug

I'm making a Wordpress theme and I get these 'Notices' repeated a lot of times when I save the options using the WP_DEBUG:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/Seozeta/wp-content/themes/seozeta/seozeta-options.php on line 997
Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/Seozeta/wp-content/themes/seozeta/seozeta-options.php on line 1000
```

The code is this:

```
foreach ($options as $value) {    
    if (isset($_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { //#997
        update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); 
    } else { 
        delete_option( $value['id'] ); //#1000
    } 
}
```

It seems the initial **isset** should work and fix the problem, but it is not. I numbered the lines affected using the comments in PHP.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: It could be that you are allowing the loop to run one extra time?

Comment: Yes, it could be. Btw, I'm using the framework Starkers, which was made using Twenty Ten theme structure. I'm not able if it is happening. Could you take a look on it? http://pastebin.com/sZ6XUaPK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `var_dump($value);`  at the beggining of this loop.
I'm pretty sure that not all options have `id` property and it may be some other bug...

To get rid of these notices, your code should look like so:

```
foreach ($options as $value) {
    if ( array_key_exists('id', $value) ) {
        if (isset($_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { //#997
            update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); 
        } else { 
            delete_option( $value['id'] ); //#1000
        }
    }
}
```

*PS. This notice has nothing to do with WordPress, so it's off-topic.*

*PPS. Some time ago I've shown you how to debug such problems, have you even tried to solve it by yourself?*

Comment: Omg, your code works perfect! I was working on it since yesterday, and yes, I tried to solve it for a lot of hours, but I need to learn more about it. (I'm gonna study about the var_dump use). Thank you a lot again, your help is much appreciated.